mb_strlen and android java show different results for same character length
In PHP
echo mb_strlen('') the result is 1
In Android Java
"".length() the result is 2
Another way to write the same char/icon
"\uD83C\uDF26".length() the result is 2
Android Encoding
Charset defaultCharset = Charset.defaultCharset() => UTF=8
(new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream())).getEncoding() => UTF-8
File encoding is UTF-8.
Questions
Why does Android Java show a different result than mb_strlen?
I assume mb_strlen result is right, and the length is 1. How can I make Java understand the string as to calculate the length to 1?
LE:
The problem is that I have a string comming from PHP server like this:
LENGTH|STRING...
example: 5|juice3|aha3|yes
If the string contains '', example 7|sample3|yes then Android Java will count it as 2 instead of 1, and will parse incorrectly the string

In Java, all Strings are comprised of UTF-16 char values, and length() returns the number of char values.  PHP's mb_strlen documentation says: "A multi-byte character is counted as 1."

String.codePointCount will give you the number of Unicode code points

Solution
Thank you all, the codePoint hint got me a starting point.
While looping char by char thought the text received from php:

changed int count = sb.length(); => int count = sb.codePointCount(0, sb.length());

changed char charAt = sb.charAt(i); to int charAt = sb.codePointAt(i);

most important


changed
                            String definition = sb.substring(i, i + defLength);

                            i += defLength - 1;

to
                            // +10% because maybe there are multi byte chars
                            StringBuilder definitionBuilder = new StringBuilder(defLength + defLength / 10);

                            int offset = 0;
                            for (int times = 0; times < defLength; times++)
                            {
                                if (sb.length() > i + offset)
                                {
                                    int codepoint = sb.codePointAt(i + offset);
                                    definitionBuilder.appendCodePoint(codepoint);
                                    offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Debug.d("Out of bounds, i = " + i + ", offset = " + offset + ", times = " + times);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            String definition = definitionBuilder.toString();

                            i += offset - 1;

The solution is not perfect, but exemplifies the fix.
Point #4 sometimes throws OutOfBounds, but it may be wrong server data, that is why the weird handling via if (sb.length() > i + offset)

In Java, String.length() returns the number of char of the string (or "Unicode code units"). A Java char is UTF-16, which means it needs two Unicode code units for some "Unicode code points" (in UTF-16, most code units are also code points, but not all code points can be represented with a single code unit).
If you want to know the number of Unicode code points, you need to use String.codePointCount(int, int). For example, for the number of code points in the entire string:
someString.codePointCount(0, someString.length())

